# How to update parent v-model using child components' prop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

My parent component has the following child component:

```html
<editor :editorBody="formData.englishBody"></editor>
```

My parent component has the following data:

```js
data () {
  return {
    // allContent: null,
    formData: {
      englishTitle: '',
      nepaliTitle: '',
      englishBody: '',
      nepaliBody: '',
      activeInactive: false,
      userId: null
    },
    rowId: null
  }
}
```

My child component has its own `v-model`, I am feeding props from parent to the child components `v-model`.

```html
<q-editor v-model="editorBody"></q-editor>
```

The `formData.englishBody` is a parent component data. I want to update `formData.englishBody` using the `editor` child component. `editor` child component is a `textarea`. Basically, I want to link child's `v-model` to parents data.

Comment: do you mean your updating logic is inside <editor/> component, and you want to use that method to update parent's data ?

Comment: No, and I thought v-model didnt need updating logic

Comment: Can you add a little more code related to the parent and child component relationship? Is `editor` the child component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that whenever the `<editor>` component updates the `editorBody` value, it does not assign to the prop directly because this is not allowed (props are one-way from parent to child), instead it needs to emit an event with the new value.

The convention is to emit an event named `update:editorBody` with the new value. Then the parent component can listen for that event and update `formData.englishBody` in response to that event:

```vue
<editor
  :editorBody="formData.englishBody"
  @update:editorBody="formData.englishBody = $event"
>
```

This can be simplified to just:

```vue
<editor :editorBody.sync="formData.englishBody">
```

This is a special [two-way binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier).

Remember, `<editor>` must be emitting the `update:editorBody` event! This means you cannot use `v-model="editorBody"` inside the `<editor>` component template.

In your `<editor>` component, change this:

```vue
<q-editor v-model="editorBody">
```

to this (assuming `<q-editor>` [didn't customize `v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model)):

```vue
<q-editor
  :value="editorBody"
  @input="$emit('update:editorBody', $event)"
>
```

Consult the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) for a more in-depth explanation and examples.

Comment: first of all, thank you, this is what I have been looking for. My child component has its own v-model, I am feeding props from parent to the child components v-model

 <q-editor
  v-model="editorBody"

Comment: Got it, I have updated my answer with usage for `<q-editor>`.