# Two way data binding between parent and child

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm learning VueJS and am trying to build a simple app where you can list, view, create, edit and delete stories. Stories are simply a title, content (just text) and a datetime. I managed to get view, list, create and delete working and am currently building the edit part.

For the edit part I thought it would be nice if I could reuse the form I use for creation. The idea is that when the user clicks the "edit button" (of a story in a list of stories) that the story is replaced by a prefilled form.

I've tried implementing this but with v-model but get the following error

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

found in

---> <StoriesForm> at src/components/StoryForm.vue
       <Stories> at src/components/Stories.vue
         <StoriesApp> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

My Stories.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-modal id="delete_story_modal">Delete?</b-modal>
    <b-container>
      <b-card v-for="story in stories" v-bind:key="story.id" :title="story.title">
      <b-card-text><router-link :to="{ path: '/'+ story.id + '/'}">{{ story.content }}</router-link></b-card-text>
      <b-card-text>{{ story.datetime }}</b-card-text>
        <b-button @click="editStory(story.id)">Edit</b-button>
        <b-button @click="deleteStory(story.id)">Delete</b-button>
      </b-card>
      <b-button @click="showForm" id="add_button" v-if="!add_story">Add story</b-button>
    </b-container>
    <StoryForm v-if="add_story" v-model="story" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import StoryForm from './StoryForm'

export default {
  name: 'Stories',
  components: {
    StoryForm
  },
  data () {
    return {
      story: {
        title: '',
        content: '',
        datetime: ''
      },
      add_story: false,
      stories: []
    }
  },
  beforeMount () {
    this.getStories()
  },
  methods: {
    async getStories () {
      // ajax request, get data, parse it, fill it
      this.stories = stories_parsed
    },
    showForm () {
      this.add_story = true;
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

And StoryForm.vue

```
<template>
  <b-container>
    <b-card>
      <form
        id="add_story"
        action="http://localhost:8000"
        method="post"
        @submit.prevent="addStory">

        <b-alert v-model="error">{{ error_msg }}</b-alert>

        <b-form-input
          v-model="story.title"
          required
          placeholder="Enter title"
        ></b-form-input>
      
        <b-form-textarea
          v-model="story.content"
          placeholder="Enter story"
        ></b-form-textarea>

        <b-button type="submit">Submit</b-button>
      </form>
    </b-card>
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Stories-form',
  props: {
    story: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
  },
  components: {},
  data () {
    return {
      error: false,
      error_msg: "no success sadly"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async addStory () {
      ...
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Since this didn't work I searched and found this: [How to update parent v-model using child components' prop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406259/how-to-update-parent-v-model-using-child-components-prop)

But couldn't get that to work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you use v2, the `v-model="story` is equivalent to two attributes: `:value="story"` and `@input="story = $event"`. This means you have to use `value` instead of `story` as your prop name, as well as have your child component emit an `input` event with the new value as the parameter.

Vue 3 is slightly different, so check out the [official documentation](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-model.html#v-model-arguments) about the v-model property and the changes made to it since v2.